# express request is called twice when no responce within 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

facing Issue :

When i hit node express API through chrome, and the responce time for the api is more that 2 minutes then the API is hit again by browser or by server (don't know), because of this multiple entries are added for same data in database.

As the 2nd API hit is always after exact 2 minutes, Seems it can be solved.

And when Api responce comes within 2 minutes it is working fine.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Pealse fine below : (Its is the demo function similar to my original function )

function testHitss(req,res){
 console.log("HIt COUNT Starts");
 sleep.sleep(150);
 console.log("Hits After Sleep");
}

Comment: Browser won't trigger API hitting automatically,, Check your logic if the response is taking more than 2 minutes you  are hitting the API again??

Comment: @subburaj , No i am not hitting API again.

Comment: O/P: 

HIt COUNT Starts


 Hits After Sleep
 HIt COUNT Starts

Comment: You would probably get better help if you showed your actual code that is being used here.

Comment: function testHitss(req,res){ 

 console.log("HIt COUNT Starts");
 sleep.sleep(150);
 console.log("Hits After Sleep");
}